# X axis label and minor tick labels do not show on Pandas scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have created a new environment with Python 3.8.12 and installed the following packages:

- `matplotlib` (3.4.3)
- `pandas` (1.3.3)
- `scikit-learn` (0.24.2)

I am running the code in a Jupyter notebook.

I am using code from two examples in the documentation for [pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

My output for the first example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 0], [7.0, 3.2, 1],
                   [6.4, 3.2, 1], [5.9, 3.0, 2]],
                  columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])

ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='length',
                      y='width',
                      c='DarkBlue')
```

does match the plot in the documentation.

However: my output for the second example

```
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x='length',
                      y='width',
                      c='species',
                      colormap='viridis')
```

does *not* match the plot in the documentation: X axis label and minor tick labels do not show on the (bottom of the) plot.

[Plot from documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/_images/pandas-DataFrame-plot-scatter-2.png)

[image: Plot from documentation]

My plot

[image: My plot]

I have tried `ax2.set_xlabel("length")` (which should be necessary) and it has no effect.

Is this a bug? Can someone please try and reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known and open issue with Pandas when using the matplotlib backend in Jupyter (noteboooks).

> This issue was reported and resolved in #10611 but returned with 0.24.0.

see [BUG: Scatterplot x-axis label disappears with colorscale when using matplotlib backend #36064](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36064)

The simplest workaround is passing `sharex=False` to pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.

Thanks to @rftr to pointing me in the right direction!